# Organisation of include files in C Cmake Project

Tags: c, cmake

I'm trying to clean up a c project (with cmake) but I'm fundamentally not understanding how to organise my c code includes.

I have a code module which is structured as follows. This is a very much cut down snippet but should be enough to provide the necessary context for this question.

```
my_proj 
    |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |-- main
        |-- CMakieLists.txt
        |-- main_app.c 
common  
    |-- state
        |-- CMakeLists.txt
        |-- state
            |-- state.h
            |-- state.c
        |-- state_sys
            |-- state_sys.h
            |-- state_sys.c
        |-- state_data
            |-- state_data.h
            |-- state_data.c
        |-- state_config
            |-- state_config.h

    |-- debug
        |-- CMakeLists.txt
        |-- debug
            |-- debug.h
            |-- debug.c
        |-- error_codes
            |-- error_codes.h
            |-- error_codes.c
```

The CMakeLists.txt files are all good. Common is added as an additional component directory. They allow me to successfully build the project. However, I've started to try and clean up the includes etc and it's quickly become apparent that I don't actually understand how it works. What worked before was a messy scatter-gun approach - deep down IU didn't understand how or why it worked. And I'm not happy with this.

Question : Why does the following NOT work?

### main module

```
**main_app.c**
#include "state.h"
#include "debug.h"
```

### debug module

```
**debug.c**
#include "state.h"
#include "debug.h"

**debug.h**
#include "error_codes.h


**error_codes.c**
#include "error_codes.h"

**error_codes.h**
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
```

### state module

```
**state.h**
#include "state_config.h"
#include "state_sys.h"
#include "state_data.h"
#include "debug.h"

**state.c**
#include "state.h"

**state_sys.h**
#include "state_config.h"

**state_sys.c**
#include "state_sys.h"

**state_data.h**
#include "state_config.h"

**state_data.c**
#include "state_data.h"

**state_config.h**
#include "state_config.h"
#include "state_sys.h"
#include "state_data.h"
#include "debug.h"
/* Std Components */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
```

Sorry, I can't think of a better way to present this information. Basically, I want to be able to include the state module  into other code modules with a single #include "state.h". And same for the debug module. Inside the state module, I've divided the code into nice neat chunks by function : sys, data, and config (a kind of top level file to stick macros and system level defines into).

My thinking was that using this strategy, each file in state would include the contents of all other files inside state via the state_config.h include in it's header file. And this would mean I only had to add in std c includes in one location too.

There are 2 separate levels at which to look at this. First why does this not work? Which seems to be the stackoverflow preference. For this I would point out the following:

When I try to compile this, I see errors like :

```
/state_data.h:47:5: error: unknown type name 'bool'

/state_data.h:124:5: error: unknown type name 'uint32_t'
```

Which I would not expect. If the compiler replaces the contents of the .h includes recursively, I would have expected the std libraries to be brought in through the #include "state_config.h" line.

However, the more interesting question is how should this work. What I mean is fixing this to the point it compiles is not my goal. I want to understand how c includes SHOULD be strcutured across a large project. This is a million times more interesting than why one of my files can't find a forward declaration for the bool type.

Comment: "Long story short, this doesn't work. So catestrophically, that you'll forgive me for not attempting to describe the symptoms." - No, we won't forgive you for not providing symptoms. It is `CMakeLists.txt` (the top-level one and ones in the subdirectories) which are responsible to setup include directories for the compilation process. You provide neither `CMakeLists.txt` nor the error message, so we have no idea what is going wrong in your project and how to fix it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev respectfully, CMakeLists.txt really has nothing to do with the question. For the sake of clarifying this - assume my_proj CMakeLists.txt included every code module as an extra_component_dir. And within each CMakeLists.txt, let's just say we add requires statements for every code module. So, everything is aware of everything else. Now, how do we arrange the #include statements. Including the CMakeLists files would only serve to clutter the question with extraneous information, at the expense of the actual question.

Comment: I'll include a few 'symptoms' too. But honestly, I think this too is clutter. It's a fundamental question about how to organise code, not why a few lines don't work as expected.

Comment: Just for the record — error messages were absolutely vital to diagnose what was going on here.

Comment: "I want to understand how c includes SHOULD be structured across a large project." - There is no single receipt which will work in all cases. It seems that your error is originated from circular dependency of your headers. This doesn't mean that circular dependency is no-no, but it should be handled with care. Actually, if the header `state_data.h` uses type `bool`, why don't include `stdbool.h` directly into it?

Answer (score 0):

You should make a hierarchy in your header files: which files are most basic, and which are most specialized. The `#include` relationship should be: specialized files include basic ones, never opposite!

The worst situation is circular `#include` — it silently doesn't work (compilers don't detect it), the effects look random and counter-intuitive, and it starts to happen when your code is already complicated.

You can use forward declarations to reduce dependencies between your header files. That way, you don't need to use `#include` so often. But more importantly, you should have a mental picture for which file can include which, according to their purpose.